# Set <img> as Base64 string Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set an image to a base64 encoded string in javascript right now I have this in my html

```
<img id="image_holder" src="" />
```

And then this in my javascript

```
document.getElementById("image_holder").src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...";
```

And then I just see this in my webpage

[image]

Instead of the image it should be.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `document.getElementById("image_holder").src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBOR..."` called before `img` element loaded into document ?

Comment: @guest271314 no its not called before

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @spenf10 Can include full `data URI` at Question ? Is `base64` string representation of image type `image/png` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.onload` event

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("image_holder").src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABUAAAAWCAYAAAAvg9c4AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAACRJREFUOI1j/M/A8J+ByoCJ2gaOGjpq6Kiho4aOGjpq6GA2FAAxTAIqi7SS4AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img id="image_holder" />
</body>
```

Comment: okay it must be something wrong with my base64 string. where does `window.onload = function() {` go? in the html file?

Comment: @spenf10 Yes, can place within `<script></script>` tags in `html`